# YII2 дыра в родной капче

Tags: php, yii2

ребята подскажите как решить проблему с  YII2 капчей , стоит капча родная yii (с ajax валидацией)  с недавнего времени обнаружилось что в логирование идет перебор левых логинов за секунду штук 20 , то есть массово приходят логин и пароль и ответ мы отдаем что неправильный логин или пароль , то есть ответ что неправильная капча нет , 
 в чем проблем или подскажите где искать дыру в капче   ?

Comment: Если нашли баг пишите на форум: https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewforum.php?f=27

Comment: Похоже надо добавить message в секцию rules для капчи в классе, который обрабатывает форму.